# Are the rings $\mathbb{C}[X]/\langle X^2- c \mathrm{Tr}(X) X \rangle$ isomorphic when $c$ ranges over a neighborhood of 0?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $X=(X_{IJ})_{I,J=1,\ldots,N}$ be a family of $N^2$ indeterminates and consider the ring $$
R_{N,c}=\mathbb{C}[X] / J_c,\quad J_c=\langle X^2 -c \mathrm{Tr}(X) X \rangle .
$$
Here the notation means that one mods out the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[X]$ by the equalities implied by the corresponding equality of matrices. This is the coordinate ring (over $\mathbb{C}$) of the affine scheme of $N\times N$ matrices $M$ satisfying $M^2=c\mathrm{Tr}(M)M$.

In [Bourget, Cabrera, Grimminger, Hanany, and Zhong - Brane Webs and Magnetic Quivers for SQCD](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.00667), the authors made the claim that these rings $R_c$ are all isomorphic for all $|c|<1/N$. Is it true or not?

Comment: Could you locate where it occurs in this 60-page paper?

Comment: To summarize context, Libli's answer shows (for given $N$) that for $c\notin\{1,1/2,\dots,1/N\}$, we have $\sqrt{J_c}=\sqrt{J_0}$, where $\sqrt{\;}$ denotes the radical of an ideal. And the answer by "guest" asserts that (for $N\ge 3$) $J_0$ is not contained in $J_c$ for any $c\neq 0$ (so an isomorphism can't be induced by the identity map).

Comment: OP, you shouldn't accept an answer which doesn't answer the question.

Comment: For $N=1$ the $J_c$  ($c\neq 1$)are clearly all equal to $J_0$. On the other hand, for $N=2$ (hence $N\ge 2$) it's also true that the $J_c$ are pairwise distinct. Indeed, consider the (local artinian) ring $S=\mathbf{C}[u,v]/(u^3,v^3,uv,v^2-(2c-1)u^2)$. Let $M$ be the diagonal matrix $\mathrm{diag}(u+v,u-v)$. Then $M^2-c'\mathrm{Tr}(M)M=(u^2+v^2)I_2-2c'u^2I_2=2(c-c')u^2I_2$. Since $u^2\neq 0$, we see that $M$ belongs to $V_{N,c'}(S)$ iff $c=c'$.

Comment: For $N=2$ I prove (in a [comment below](https://mathoverflow.net/a/354539/14094)) that the (non-reduced) $\mathbf{C}$-algebras $R_{2,c}$, for $c\notin\{1,1/2,0\}$ are all isomorphic.

Answer (score 7):

The isomorphism of the reduced underlying spaces is rather a trivial fact from undergraduate linear algebra. Let $X \in \mathcal{M}_{N}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $X^2 - \alpha \mathrm{Tr}(X).X = 0$, with $|\alpha| < \dfrac{1}{N}$. If $\mathrm{Tr}(X) = 0$ then $X$ is in the nilpotent cone, and vice-versa, if $X^2=0$, then $\mathrm{Tr}(X) = 0$.

Assume by absurd that $\mathrm{Tr}(X) \neq 0$, then $X$ is diagonalizable and its eigenvalues are $0$ and $\alpha \mathrm{Tr}(X)$. Let's denote by $m$ the multiplicity of $\alpha \mathrm{Tr}(X)$ as an eigenvalue of $X$, (note that $m \leq N$). Then we have:

$$ \mathrm{Tr}(X) = m \times \alpha \mathrm{Tr}(X),$$
which forces  $\mathrm{Tr}(X) = 0$ since $|m \times \alpha|<1$, a contradiction. We thus find that for all $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha|< \dfrac{1}{N}$ the scheme of matrices defined by $X^2 - \alpha.\mathrm{Tr}(X).X = 0$ is isomorphic to the scheme of matrices defined by $X^2 = 0.$

**EDIT** : In a first version of my answer I claimed that my "topological" argument was sufficient to prove that the rings introduced by the OP are isomorphic. This not true as these rings are not reduced. Thus, an extra argument is needed to go from the isomorphism of the reduced underlying spaces to the isomorphisms of the actual schemes.

Comment: Did you prove that the rings are isomorphic? Your argument only shows that the MaxSpec of the rings are the same. At least I don't see how you go from there to having the rings be isomorphic. Is the ideal obviously a radical ideal and I just don't see it?

Comment: Why does the condition on $X$ force $X$ diagonalisable?

Comment: @JohannesHahn : The nilpotent cone is well-known to be an integral scheme. Since the scheme defined by $X^2 - \alpha \mathrm{Tr}(X).X$ is a small deformation of the nilpotent cone, it is equally integral.

Comment: @LSpice Because it's minimal polynomial divides the polynomial $T^2-\alpha Tr(X)T$ and if $\alpha Tr(X) \neq 0$, then this polynomial has only simple roots. The minimal polynomial having simple roots is one of the equivalent characterisations of diagonalisability.

Comment: @Libli Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @JohannesHahn : I withdraw my answer to your comment. The ideal $\langle X^2 \rangle$ is not radical since it doesn't contain $Tr(X)$ but only $Tr(X)^{N+1}$. So you are right, I only proved that the underlying integral spaces (nilpotent cone) are isomorphic.

Comment: Thanks, that was very simple....

Comment: @YujiTachikawa : You are welcome. Note however that my answer is not complete since I only proved that the underlying reduced rings are isomorphic, not the actual rings you introduced. I have thought a lot about it in the last two days, and I can't really find an argument which would extend the isomorphism from the reduced underlying spaces to the actual schemes. (to be continued)

Comment: @DavidESpeyer : You are right, I need to assume that the hyperplane is not a zero divisor, which is not the case here, so I will delete my comment.

Comment: @Libli : Hi, I'm one of the authors of the paper, first of all thanks for the answer! I would be interested in seeing your argument using the Hilbert series and understanding why it was incomplete.

Comment: @Antoine: if $f \in A$ is of degree $d$ and not a zero divisor, then we have an exact sequence $0 \longrightarrow A[d] \stackrel{\times f}\longrightarrow A \longrightarrow A/(f) \longrightarrow 0.$ Since $HS(A[d]) = t^{d}HS(A)$, we get $HS(A/f) = (1-t^{d})HS(A)$. It follows that the equality of Hilbert series of $B/f$ and $A/f$ implies the equality of the Hilbert series of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: But this does not apply to your situation, as $\mathrm{Tr}(X)$ is nilpotent. However if one can prove that the kernel of multiplication by $\mathrm{Tr}(X)$ in both rings are isomorphic, then the 5-lemma would show that the actual rings are isomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that these rings are isomorphic. If $\mathbb C[\epsilon]$ is the dual numbers then $3\times 3$  matrix of the form 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda\epsilon & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \mu \epsilon \end{pmatrix}$$
induces a map $R_c \rightarrow \mathbb C[\epsilon]$, for suitable choice of $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{C}$, but $A^2\neq 0$. This shows the ideals generated by $X^2$ and $X^2-c Tr(X) X$ are distinct, but does not exclude the existence of some other isomorphism.

Comment: This is an interesting comment but the first sentence should better be removed as it's confusing. Actually, while this works only for $N\ge 3$, I give (in a comment to the original post) a proof that the defining ideals are distinct also working for $N=2$, using evaluations in other $\mathbf{C}$-algebras.

Comment: For $N=2$ we get by hand an isomorphism between the $\mathbf{C}$-algebras: mapping the matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix}w+x&y\\z&w-x\end{pmatrix}$ to $\begin{pmatrix}sw+x&y\\z&sw-x\end{pmatrix}$ maps the variety $V_{2,c}$ (of equation $M^2=c\mathrm{Tr}(M)M$) to the variety $V_{2,c'}$ with $2c'-1=(2c-1)/s^2$, provided that $c,c'\notin\{1,1/2\}$. By this I mean schematically, i.e., over any commutative $\mathbf{C}$-algebra. Indeed, for $c\neq 2$, the variety $V_{2,c}$ is checked (by plain computation) to be given by those matrices $M=M(w,x,y,z)$ such that $0=wx=wy=wz=x^2+yz-w^2(2c-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the answer to this question is still of interest, but I can prove that for $c$ in a $1$-dimensional (open) subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^1$, the projective schemes $\mathrm{Proj}(R_{N,c})$ are isomorphic. Unfortunately, the proof I have recquires some advanced techniques. I will still post it, as someone may see some drastic simplifcations that can be made.

First consider the linear map $\mathbb{C}[X] \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}[X]$ defined by:
$$T_{\alpha} : M \longrightarrow T_{\alpha}(M) = M - \alpha \mathrm{Tr}(M).I_N.$$ It is a linear isomorphism provided $\alpha \neq \dfrac{1}{N}$. Furthermore, if one puts $M = T_{\alpha}(U)$, for $U = T_{\alpha}^{-1}(M)$, we have:
$$ M^2 - c\mathrm{Tr}(M).M = 0 \ \Leftrightarrow \ U^2 - (2 \alpha + c(1-\alpha.N))\mathrm{Tr}(U).U + \alpha(c(1-\alpha.N)+\alpha) \mathrm{Tr}(U)^2.I_N=0$$
In particular, for $\alpha = \frac{c}{cN-1}$, we have:
$$M^2 - c\mathrm{Tr}(M).M = 0 \ \Leftrightarrow U^2 - \frac{c}{c.N-1} \mathrm{Tr}(U).U = 0.$$
As $\alpha = \frac{c}{cN-1} \neq \dfrac{1}{N}$, the linear map $T_{\alpha}$ is an isomorphism and it maps isomorphically:
$$T_{\alpha} : R_{N,\frac{c}{cN-1}} \stackrel{\sim}\longrightarrow R_{N,c}.$$

For $\alpha = \frac{1-s}{2}$, this transformation is the one exhibited by @Ycor in the case $N=2$.

We define the map $\varphi : \mathbb{C} \backslash \{\frac{1}{N} \} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by :
$$\varphi(c) = \frac{c}{cN-1}$$
and we note that $\varphi \circ \varphi = \mathrm{id}$. The map $\varphi$ has exactly two fixed points : $0$ and $\frac{2}{N}$. If $c_0 \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \{0, \frac{2}{N} \}$, the sequence $(a_n = \varphi^{n}(c_0))_{n \geq 0}$ contains infintely many terms. The above argument then shows that the set:

$$\{c \in \mathbb{C}, \ \mathrm{Proj}(R_{N,c}) \simeq \mathrm{Proj}(R_{N,c_0}) \}$$ contains infinitely many points. I will now prove that this set is in fact a $1$-dimensional subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^1$. This is where I need some big guns, hopefully the argument may be simplified a lot.

Let $V \subset \mathrm{Proj}(\mathbb{C}[X]) \times \mathbb{C}$ the subscheme defined by the equation $X^2 - c\mathrm{Tr}(X)X = 0$ ($c$ is the name for the coordinate in the second factor) and let $p : V \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ the natural projection. By generic flatness, there exists a non-empty open subscheme $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, such that:

$$ p|_{p^{-1}(U)} : V_U = p^{-1}(U) \longrightarrow U$$ is flat. Note that $U$ is not equal to $\mathbb{C}$. Indeed $p^{-1}(0)$ is irreducible (but non-reduced!), while $p^{-1}(\frac{1}{N})$ contains (at least) two components of different dimension. We denote by $Z$ the complement of $U$ in $\mathbb{A}^1$, this is a closed (hence finite) subscheme of $\mathbb{C}$. As a consequence $U$ contains one of the $a_i$ defined above, say $a_{j_0}$.

We put $\mathcal{Q}$ be the Hilbert polynomial of $p^{-1}(a_{j_0}) = \mathrm{Proj}(R_{N,a_{j_0}}) \simeq \mathrm{Proj}(R_{N,c_0})$ and let $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{Q}}$ be the Hilbert scheme of subschemes of $\mathrm{Proj}(\mathbb{C}[X])$ having Hibert polynomial $\mathcal{Q}$. It is known that $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{Q}}$ is proper over $\mathbb{C}$, hence of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$.

The map $p : V_U \longrightarrow U$ being flat and the Hilbert polynomial of a fiber being $\mathcal{Q}$, the universal property of the Hibert scheme insures the existence of a map:
$$ f : U \longrightarrow \mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{Q}}$$
such that the pull-back by $f$ of the universal family over $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{Q}}$ is $V_U$.

Now we consider the action of $\mathrm{G} = \mathrm{PGL}(\mathbb{C}^{n^2})$ on $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{Q}}$ and we let $\mathrm{G}.f(a_{j_0})$ be the orbit of $f(a_{j_0})$ under $\mathrm{G}$ in $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{Q}}$. This is a locally-closed finite type subscheme of $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{Q}}$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

The scheme $\mathrm{G}.f(a_{j_0})$ parametrizes all the subschemes of $\mathrm{Proj}(\mathbb{C}[X])$ which are linearly isomorphic to $f(a_{j_0})$. Furthermore, the property of $f$ with respect to the universal family of $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{Q}}$ and the construction of the sequence $(a_n)$ imply the inclusion:
$$\{a_n, \ n \in \mathbb{N} \} \subset f^{-1}(\mathrm{G}.f(a_{j_0})).$$

As $\mathbb{A}^1$ is (obviously) affine and $\mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{Q}}$ is proper over $\mathbb{C}$, the scheme $f^{-1}(\mathrm{G}.f(a_{j_0}))$ is of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$. As a consequence $f^{-1}(\mathrm{G}.f(a_{j_0}))$ can not be zero-dimensional. Indeed, if it were, it would have infinitely many distincts connected components (the $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 0}$) and this is impossible for a scheme of finite-type over $\mathbb{C}$.

We deduce that $f^{-1}(\mathrm{G}.f(a_{j_0}))$ is positive dimensional in $\mathbb{A}^1$, and so it is Zariski dense. All fibers iof the form $p^{-1}(c)$, for $c \in f^{-1}(\mathrm{G}.f(a_{j_0})) \}$ are isomorphic, because $f^* W = V_U$ and all $W_{y}$, for $y \in  \mathrm{G}.f(a_{j_0})\}$ are isomorphic, where:
$$W \longrightarrow \mathcal{H}_{\mathcal{Q}}$$
is the universal family.

End of the proof.

(Minor) comment : it rather frustrating, but I can't prove that $0$ is the open subset where the $R_{N,c}$ are isomorphic to each other.